# scrollview not moving

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Quite a simple bug. Unable to resolve.

I added a scrollview to my application. Next I added a view to this scrollview which is out of scrollview bounds. I was hoping the scrollview would allow my view to be scrolled.

but the view is not scrollable. i.e. I added a button to it, to see it is scrolling horizontally. However its not.

The kind of functionality I'm looking is like infinite scrolling with a long list of buttons, similar to http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/infinitescrollview

How can I achieve this?

Comment: just increase the contentsize of your scrollview oly if the contents extends the height of view the scrollview will scroll

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know whether it helps you or not

Comment: None of the options worked. Still do not understand why

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property

```
[scrollview setContentSize:CGRectMake(x, y, width,height)];
```

*width* = 320*no of views you want to add in scrollview

*height* = You can put it height view *e.g.* 460;

and set frame

```
scrollview.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, self.view.frame.size.width, height) //self.view.frame.size.width=320 (iphone)
```

This is the simplest way to achieve above

and if you want it with the button click then use scrollview property

```
[scrollview setContentOffset:(CGPoint) animated:BOOL]
or
[scrollview setContentOffset:(CGPoint)]
```

hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

try

```
scr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scr.frame.size.width, contentHeight);
```