# App Is Not Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to get my view controller to scroll, but it won't work. Any clue to what's wrong?

```
    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];

    GGBoxView *boxee = [[GGBoxView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 56, 144, 120)];
    [scroll addSubview:boxee];
```

This code is part of my GGViewController class.

Comment: exact duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824435/uiscrollview-not-scrolling), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612591/scrollview-not-moving) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417414/uiscrollview-not-scrolling) too!

Comment: Haha sorry i actually did not search fo app is not scorlling i saw some other questions like Add ScrollView to Existing ViewController but never found those other ones on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are setting `frame` `CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)` and `content size` `CGSizeMake(320, 480)` which is equal, `Content size` must be greater then actual size of `scrollView` in order to exhibit scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

you are giving `scrollview` `content size` as 480 it means it takes entire screen, for scrolling the screen you have to give more `content size` then only it'l `scrolls` otherwise it won't scroll.

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);
```